# Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface unavailable

Tags: windows, networking, wmi

I am trying to use a VBScript to query bandwidth usage of my network card. But the query errors out.

```
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
        ("select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_TCPIP_NetworkInterface " ) 
    For Each objItem in colItems 
    WScript.Echo objItem.CurrentBandwidth
    NEXT
```

I also tried this variation, and it doesn't work either.

```
    Set objInstances = objWMIService.InstancesOf("Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface",48)
```

The following error is shown at the respective line numbers

```
    (null): 0x80041001
```

I am using windows 7. Ran the script as Admin. Checked that Admin has access to WMI as mentioned [here](http://community.spiceworks.com/help/Troubleshooting_WMI). I am able to list all the network adapters using this [code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I tried using the powershell WMI browser and such a class name (Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface) is not listed. Same when using the WMI Explorer from [here](http://www.ks-soft.net/hostmon.eng/wmi/index.htm). When i execute below query in the WMI Explorer, it says invalid query

```
    select Name from Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface
```

I am able to find Win32_PerfFormattedData listed in both the explorers. No instances exist when choose this class in the KS-Soft WMI explorer. No classes exist that begin with the name Win32_PerfFormattedData_xxxxxxxx.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, you need two commas, for example :

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface",,48)